# How to asynchronous reload the UIImage in one UITableView cell/row?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

in the UITableView that have some cells, and each cell have tow UIImage, and i will update the UIImage asynch for performance.  but there is a question, how can i only reload the UIImageView in cell when a image pulled from the Web.

i kown can reload a whole cell with methoed "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths", but i just want to kown is there have a method can only reload the UIView object which is necessary to be reload (i.e. a image or a label) in the cell.

BTW, i found the methoed "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" will execute the method "heightForRowAtIndexPath" for all cells when i just reload one cell.  is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sample code [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) from apple is what you want.

Comment: BTW, i found the methoed "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" will execute the method "heightForRowAtIndexPath" for all cells when i just reload one cell.  am i right?

Comment: @rotyger You can check it by setting a breakpoint in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to your custom cell calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Then update its image property running this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.someImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

You'll be loading at most 6 images concurrently because that's the limit of NSURLConnection.